# How can i send a 2d array to client with tcp/ip; My code prints nothing

Tags: c, tcp

************SERVER*********

```
char arr[20][20];

int i,j; 
 for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    for(j=0;j<20;j++){
        send(sock,&arr[i][j],sizeof(char),0);
    }
}
```

*******CLIENT***************************

```
char arr[20][20];
int i,j; 
 for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    for(j=0;j<20;j++){
        recv(sock,&arr[i][j],sizeof(char),0);
        printf("%s",arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check what `send` and `recv` returns? Have you any other kind of error checking in your code? Could you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] to show us? And have you tried to debug either the server of the client, or used a network packet sniffer to see if the server is sending the packets?

Comment: As a qualified guess about the problem though: `printf("%s",arr[i][j]);`. What argument does the `%s` format expect? Doesn't the compiler warn you about this?

Comment: I turned it into %c but nothing again. Also i try to send some simple messages to client and it works perfectly  but now with 2d it doesnt work

Comment: Strongly suggest passing that [20][20] array in one 'gulp' of 400 bytes

Comment: but how i will pass it???